# Why can't I get React Native debugging to work in VSCode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I've looked at so many tutorials, and they seem so simple, but I just can't get debugging to work (running Expo, not ready to eject, that's a whole other level of craziness).

I've tried creating an app with `create-react-native-app` and also with `expo-init` which appear to be the same thing. I start running the app with `yarn start` and I can see the app in Expo. I select "Attach to Packager" in VSCode, and it fails every time.

I've added `"react-native.packager.port": 19005` to my settings.json but I can't seem to find the right port. My Metro screen has so many different ports in so many different places:

- The terminal where I ran `yarn start` says

```
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19003
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19005.
Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on the connected Android device.
Tunnel ready.

  exp://192.168.1.5:19004
```

- The chrome window is at `localhost:19003`
- The first line of the Metro Bundler terminal says `Starting Metro Bundler on port 19005.`
- Later in the terminal it says `Opening exp://127.0.0.1:19004 in iOS simulator`
- In the sidebar it says `exp://192.168.1.5:19004`, which is reflected in the Dev settings screen in the iOS simulator.

I've tried changing the port in `"react-native.packager.port": 19005` to every number between 19000 and 19005 and they all fail. They all say:

```
Could not debug. Cannot attach to packager. 
Are you sure there is a packager and it is running in the port 19003? 
If your packager is configured to run in another port make sure to add that to the settings.json. (error code 504)
```

with, of course, the currently set port.

#### HELP ME!!!

Comment: I am also facing the same. Do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`react-native.packager.port` should be changed to the port the Browser's developer tool's is running on. Stopping and Restarting the npm server once again worked for me.